# How to increase gcloud re-authentication timeout , currently it expires every 1 hr

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

I run below commands

- to authenticate to google cloud with my corporate email id (ldap)
- to update my kubeconfig file on my on-premis machine
- access to k8s control plane from on-premis machine using kube-api-proxy. ( I use this proxy to reach control plane as there is no VPC peering between GKE control plane vpc and my corporate network)

```
gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser  ## I use corporate email id to authenticate
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <>gke_cluster_name> --region <region> --project <gcp_project>
export https_proxy=<kube_api_proxy>:8118  ## Proxy to connect to k8s controlplane
kubectl get no
```

Every 1 hour, I have to repeat above steps to re-authenticate as I fail with below error otherwise when I try to connect to k8S

```
Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud 
config config-helper --format=json": err=exit status 1 output= stderr=ERROR: gcloud crashed (TransportError):
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token 
(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Request blocked by Privoxy')))
```

Is there a way I can increase this timeout , lets say 4 hours or so, as I have a job that runs more than 1 hour and it fails in middle due to timeout.

Answer (score 5):

The CLI **gcloud** creates OAuth Access Tokens that are valid for 3,600 seconds. That is the maximum lifetime supported for non-organization projects. This is also the maximum lifetime for **user** identities, which you are using.

To increase the token lifetime for an Organization, you must create credentials from a service account and set the Organization Policy Constraint **constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension** which supports tokens with a lifetime of 12 hours. [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)

However, I am not aware of a method of using that constraint within the CLI without modifying the source code of the CLI, which is written in Python. I have never made this change because writing my own code is much easier.

Instead, write your own token generator. There are many source code examples on the Internet. I wrote an article which includes source code [link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/). Change this line in my code to the time desired:

```
# Set how long this token will be valid in seconds
expires_in = 3600   # Expires in 1 hour
```

**In Summary:**

1. You must be part of a Google Cloud Organization.
2. You must create credentials from a service account.
3. You must set the Organization Policy Constraint.
4. The constraint must include the email address of allowed service accounts.

Comment: This article contains additional information on how to "Set session length for Google Cloud services":
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756

Comment: @bambam - Your link is for related configuration parameters. However, make sure you understand the difference from the ones used in my answer. Session expiration and token expiration are different items.